# How can I activate Git messages at Eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse, git

I was checking how each theme looked in Eclipse. After checking some of them, I clicked on Restore Defaults for Editors and Appearance. However, I stopped seeing the git messages next to the project I am currently working. I just would like be able to see them again because they were so useful.

Comment: Is it possible that the project is no longer considered as "shared" (Team > Share project > Git)? Or is it a matter of switching back to the right perspective?

Comment: My project is shared. For example, doing what you suggest I get git options as Add to Index, Commit, Push, ..., The problem is that I can't see the state of my repository at the Package Explorer.